# Whats difference between create table vs create virtual table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, create-table

Does create Virtual table statement makes table solely on  the RAM? If thats true how can you deal with big data with less ram devices?

Demonstrate the mechanism of statement - create virtual table, in sqllite.

If you want example than heres an easy statement:

```
   //Create a FTS3 Virtual Table
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE + " USING fts3(" +
        KEY_CUSTOMER + "," +
        KEY_NAME + "," +
        KEY_ADDRESS1 + "," +
        KEY_ADDRESS2 + "," +
        KEY_CITY + "," +
        KEY_STATE + "," +
        KEY_ZIP + "," +
        KEY_SEARCH + "," +
        " UNIQUE (" + KEY_CUSTOMER + "));";
```

Comment: FTS tables ignore constraints like UNIQUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A virtual table is not implemented with the usual mechanisms; instead, all operations on it are redirected to some virtual table module.

What that actually means depends on how the virtual table module chooses to implement them.

There are virtual table modules that access data that is stored outside the database.
But in the case of FTS, creating the virtual table also creates several [shadow tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#shadow_tables) in the same database, which store the actual table data and the contents of the full-text index. This implies that you do not have to manage any external data, and that all operations are automatically protected by the usual transaction management.

Answer (score 1):

You can see a good explanation in this link:
https://sqlite.org/vtab.html

> From the perspective of an SQL statement, the virtual table object looks like any other table or view. But behind the scenes, queries and updates on a virtual table invoke callback methods of the virtual table object instead of reading and writing on the database file.
>
> A virtual table might represent an in-memory data structures. Or it might represent a view of data on disk that is not in the SQLite format. Or the application might compute the content of the virtual table on demand.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createvtab.html) is quite clear:

> A virtual table is an interface to an external storage or computation
>   engine that appears to be a table but does not actually store
>   information in the database file.

Virtual tables *could* be resident in RAM.  More often they would be disk files of some sort or stored in another database.